Extract substring in URL
My URL is
https://abc.xxxxx.yyy/data/HNX/2024/BCTC/VN/QUY2/xxx_Baocaotaichinh_Q2_2024_Hopnhat.zip
I need extract xxx_Baocaotaichinh_Q2_2024_Hopnhat substring
Please help me extract it by regex in javascript
My regex is [^\/]+.$
The next is  .*[^\.zip]
I tried many regex syntax

In what programming language? A lot of them have URL libraries that would be able to help you get the base name minus the extension

javascript language

@XanhCloudMarketing, can value may have / at last of it?

what is the result you get?

Duplicate: REGEX: Capture Filename from URL without file extension

I have the answer from Phil. Thank you so much
